# Store javascript function return in a variable

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I am trying to return a value from a javascript function that checks whether a string of multiple email addresses contains valid emails:

validateEmail function:

```
validateEmail = function(email) {
    var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    return re.test(email);
} // this returns true/false

var emails = ["asdf@yahoo.com", "dfdf@yahoo.com"]

var emailResult = function(emails) {
        var result;
        emails.forEach(function(email) {
            if(validateEmail(email.trim()) === false) {
                result = false;
            }
        });
        return result
    }
```

If any of the emails are valid, I want `emailResult` to be equal to false. However, when I run `console.log(emailResult)`, I just get a print out of my function's code. Can someone help?

Thanks!!

Comment: `console.log(emailResult(emails))`? (You also want to start with `var result = true;`)

Comment: emailResult is the function itself, if you want the return value, you have to call the function. emailResult([]) will return the initial result definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending the function itself to console.log(). You need to call the function, and pass the result of the function to console.log(), like so:

```
console.log(emailResult(emails));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need to invoke the function. You could get it to work if you did `console.log(validateEmail("test@"test.com"));` instead or you can restructe like so:

```
function validateEmail (email) {
       var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
       return re.test(email);
} // this returns true/false

var emails = ["asdf@yahoo.com", "dfdf@yahoo.com"]

var emailResult = function(emails) {
       var result;
       emails.forEach(function(email) {
              if(validateEmail(email.trim()) === false) {
                     result = false;
              }
       });
       return result
}

var theEmails = validateEmail("Test@Test.com");
```